# Extracting valid date from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, validation, date

I need to extract a valid date from a list of random strings. The date can be present in any date format("01/25/16", "25/01/2016", "20-01-2016", "3-Nov-2016" etc) with different kind of separators.

I tried the using Date.parse() and new Date() but these method also return a valid value for any number passed which ideally is not a date.

For Ex: Date.parse("1") = 978336000000

My current solution is to check each string with the following regex

```
  if(!string.match(/^\d+$|[a-zA-Z]+\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]*/) && (string.length > 7)) {
    const date = Date.parse(string)
    return (!isNaN(date))
  }
```

This regex works to identify date strings like "01/25/16", "25/01/2016", "20-01-2016" 
This regex matches most of the regular text like "100", "hello", "123hello", "1h ello12" and lets in values like "123-123", "01/25/16" and Date.parse() identifies pretty good.

But this misses the date string like "23-Nov-2016" so I added one more regex along with previous one

```
    if(((!string.match(/^\d+$|[a-zA-Z]+\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]*/) && (string.length > 7)) || ((string.match(/^\d+$|[a-zA-Z]+\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]*/) && string.toLowerCase.match(/jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec/))) {
       const date = Date.parse(string)
       return (!isNaN(date))
    }
```

I definitely believe that there exists a much simpler solution than using this large sets of regex in javascript.

EDIT : I don't control the date input rules to specifically validate certain formats.

Comment: ask the user to enter the date in dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: If you want it simpler, let datejs handle it for you.
https://github.com/datejs/Datejs What you want is to use Date.parse()

Comment: if you need to check for mm/dd/yy and dd/mm/yyyy, how do you know you won't get formats of dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yyyy?  This question doesn't make sense as a real problem to solve.

Comment: also, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) --- _Note: Parsing of strings with Date.parse is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies._

Comment: @andi : The problem here is I don't control the input. I just get a list of strings which may or may not contain a date. I am just looking for a solution which might work for most of the cases if not all.

Comment: Where do those lists of strings come from?

Comment: @andi: These strings are excerpts from different documents representing reports and can there is no restriction on how these documents are written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there **is** a better solution than using a set of regular expressions.

The problem is that there are at least a million different ways to write the same date. It seems like no matter what date formats you have planned for, your users will always come up with something that doesn't fit. So I approached this in the following way for a project I'm working on:

1. Make a list of acceptable date formats.
2. Tell the users not to use different formats and enforce it via client-side validation.

In my case, I'm living in the US, and dates are usually written like 'M/D/YY'. To allow for a *reasonable* range of variation, I wrote my code to accept `M/D/YY`, `M/D/YYYY`, and `M/D` (where the current year is substituted if the year is omitted). These formats are recognized using regular expressions then parsed using the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

You may want to expand the list of permitted formats if your users habitually use them - that's fine. But the important thing is to realize that you can't plan for all possible formats - there are just too many variations.

If you can meet your users' expectations 90% of the time (with the most common formats) and train your users that these are the accepted formats, you'll have happy users and date parsing code that's not 10,000 lines long.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. As you rightly said there are many ways for user to input date if we don't enforce a client side validation. I am making sure that my regex validates most of the possibilities out there and get the date out of it for my purpose.